# share MJ with friends

Tags: discord, neural-network, discord.js, bots

I'm using someone else's discord server where my prompt is coming from someone who has a midjourney subscription

but for this to work, I have to write /command/imagine prompt$ "textpromt"

Basically, i'm write a prompt in her server, and Midjourney would handle it as written he.

how to implement such a bot?

i think, need try to
but it's can work?

```
bottoken = 'tokenbot'
serverid = 'idserver'
webhookurl = 'URL'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author.bot:
    return

if message.content.startswith('!sendasowner'):
    server = bot.get_guild(int(server_id))
    webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(webhook_url, adapter=discord.RequestsWebhookAdapter())
    await webhook.send(message.content[len('!sendasowner'):], username=server.owner.name, avatar_url=server.owner.avatar_url)
```

bot.run(bot_token)

Comment: Could you clarify your question?